# Why does traversing a tree in level order cause a value error?

Tags: python, tree

I am writing a function to solve the following problem:

"Given the root of a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes' values. (i.e., from left to right, level by level).

e.g. Input: root = [3,9,20,null,null,15,7]
Output: [[3],[9,20],[15,7]]
"

Here is my code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: TreeNode):
        queue = deque([root])
        output = []

        if not root:
            return output

        while queue:
            root = queue.popleft()
            output.append(root.val)
            queue.append(root.left)
            queue.append(root.right)

        return output
```

I seem to be getting the error: "Nonetype has no attribute val" for the line output.append(root.val). Any ideas why?

I thought I covered the edge case when root is empty.

P.S. I know my code doesn't solve the problem, as it doesn't address the 'level's by not separating each level into different arrays.

But I want to just see if my code traverses the tree in the correct order first!

Comment: `root.left` or `root.right` can be `None` and you append them to `queue` after the `if not root` clause.

Comment: Of course! Thanks

Comment: So after the root = queue.popleft() line, if I add an "if root ==None: continue" does that work?

Comment: Why do you ask? Did you try?